# Site keeps redirecting to core/install.php

Tags: 8

I keep having this problem of drupal redirecting to `core/install.php` as shown below:

[image]

I already set the `max_allowed_packet` to 64MB on AWS RDS. I am not sure what else I am missing. Please help

The error in the logs is:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
>   _drupal_shutdown_function_handle_exception() (previously declared in /var/www/html/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc:1066) in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/drupal/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1066

and the following is my composer.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx/yyy",
  "description": "zzz",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "QQQ EEE",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.108",
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
    "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
    "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
    "drupal/core": "^8.7.0",
    "drupal/ldap": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/redis": "^1.1",
    "drupal/s3fs": "^3.0",
    "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
    "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
    "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.7.0"
  },
  "conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
    ],
    "files": ["load.environment.php"]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
    "patchLevel": {
      "drupal/core": "-p2"
    },
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
      "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
      "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
      "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
      "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
      "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
    },
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "initial": {
        ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
        ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error showing up in the logs?

Comment: CloudWatch keep showing `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 571 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"`. Let me try to deploy `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` in settings.php

Comment: Ok it says `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _drupal_shutdown_function_handle_exception() (previously declared in /var/www/html/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc:1066) in /var/www/html/vendor/drupal/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1066`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a problem with your installation. You have two copies of core, as can be seen from the two paths in the error message:

/var/www/html/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc

/var/www/html/vendor/drupal/core/includes/bootstrap.inc

You should not have a copy of core in your vendor directory. That needs to be removed, though it may also break your site. Make sure to clear the registry `drush cr` or equivalent after removing that directory.

Comment: How is it possibly happened in the first place? I use Composer to install

Comment: By default, composer will install to the vendor folder. The template for Drupal that most people use (https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) adds some code so that the library is installed to /web/core. Somehow you have ended up with both, indicating a problem in your `composer.json`, either now, or at some point in the past.

Comment: I just add in my composer.json. See if there are any issues with it

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ – Try `$ cd path/to/drupal-project && rm -rf vendor/ && rm composer.lock && composer install`. Then clear Drupal cache, run updates and cron and flush cache again. Then check your `.htaccess`.

Comment: yup that works. Thanks!. I upvoted the solution.